# What is difference between allocated memory and existing address in CPP?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int *n=new int;
*n=20;
cout<<n<<endl<<*n<<endl<<&n;
```

When compiled above code I get output as

> 0xa41510
> 20
> 0x6ffe08

Now what is difference in **'n'** and **'&n'**. If new memory is allocated to 'n' then why its address is different?

Sorry if this is kind of silly.

Comment: Pointers are also objects, so doing `&n` will give you the address of the pointer itself. `n` is the address where the memory was allocated.

Comment: *Hint:* The difference between `n` and `&n` when `n` is a pointer (such as `int*`) is the same as the difference between `n` and `&n` when `n` is not a pointer.

Comment: `n` is the variable that holds the value returned by the `new int` expression.   `&n` is the address of that variable.    The address of a variable is its location in memory, and its value is determined by the *contents* at that location, not the address.      Similarly, if we do `int x = 2`,  `x` is would be the variable that holds the value `2`, and `&x` would be the address of `x` (and highly unlikely to have a value of `2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     n
----------- 
| 0xa41510 |
------------
address : 0x6ffe08

--------
|  20  |
--------
 address : 0xa41510
```

**When you write**

```
int *n=new int
```

> you are telling that you need a memory to store an integer type so new returns the address of memory location allocated which is then stored in *n*

After statement

```
*n=20
```

You have stored 20 at address stored in *n*

> **NOTE** : '*' is the indirection or dereferencing operator when applied to a pointer, it accesses the object the pointer points to.

So now when we print output

```
std::cout<<n; 

prints 0xa41510 

As this is the value stored in n which is the address of memory location where 20 is stored
```

```
std::cout<<*n ;

prints 20 

> As it prints the value at the address stored in n
```

```
std::cout<<&n;  

prints 0x6ffe08 

> As it the address of n
```

**NOTE**

> & produces the address of the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can think that 'int*' is a new type, such as typedef int * INT_POINTER.
If you understand the relation between int and int*, there is no problem to understand the relation between INT_POINTER and INT_POINTER*. It's same.

ex:) The meaning of below two lines is same.

```
int a = 0; int * b = &a;
INT_POINTER c = new int; INT_POINTER* d = &c;
```